# vbs xmlhttp responseText Truncated?

Tags: http, post, vbscript, httpwebresponse

Hello all i have a simple vbs script that is grabbing a url(with values using GET) and I need to parse thru the text. However the responsetext i am getting is not the full response. i am getting a string that is 1000 in length however i know the response should be more like 5000.

```
Function getServer(server_hostname)
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")
    objHTTP.open "GET", "http://someurl/ServerInfo.asp", False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.send "B1=GO!!&Server=" + server_hostname 

    getServer = objHTTP.responseText
End Function

serverStr = getServer(server_hostname)
msgbox(Len(serverStr))
```

Is there a limitation on how much can be returned? Thank you for your help.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

So i change my function to:

```
Function getServer(server_hostname)
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.open "GET", "http://someurl/ServerInfo.asp?B1=GO!!&Server=" + server_hostname , False
    'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html"
    'objHTTP.send "B1=GO!!&Server=" + server_hostname 
    objHTTP.send

    getServer = objHTTP.responseText
End Function
```

And now it works...no idea why.

Comment: Ok so I ran wireshark, and sure enough I am not getting what I expected, however if I paste the same URL in IE or FIREFOX then view it's source I get the expected results....what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum MsgBox length is 1024 characters.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_msgbox.asp

Comment: Yea,  but the msgbox is returning the length of the string, not the string itself.

Comment: The answer to that question is no, there is no limit as far as I'm aware. Try running netmon, wireshark or possibly fiddler and see if you have something else going on. Also you could try using "CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")" instead and see if you get different behavior.